# The value of a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Finding the value of the limit

Let

$ x_{n} $ =$ \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+....+\sqrt{n}}}}$

then

$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=$?

Comment: The limit exists, but, apparently, [nobody knows its exact value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html).